# Disoriented vs. Disorientated

Tags: verbs, adjectives, suffixes, transatlantic-differences

In the U.S., we seemingly prefer the former to the latter. However, I was sitting with my friends when one of them stated that he was "disorientated" while we were playing a video game.

My theory, at the time, was that he made the language connection between a "youtube game commentator" and "disoriented", resulting in a mash-up of the two words. Due to the rise of usage in the word "commentator", at least in the U.S., it made plenty of sense.

However, I just did some look-up this morning, out of curiosity, and it seems that the British prefer the latter to the former. It seemed a bit odd to me, so I asked some acquaintances in an [SO Chat Room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript), and an interesting proposal was made.

Perhaps "Disoriented" is more of an adjective, where "Disorientated" is more appropriately a verb.

An example would be:

- *Adjective:* He became disoriented in the forest.
- *Verb:* He disorientated himself in the forest.

Thoughts?

Comment: No, the British simply like to use the lengthenated and more redundantized version of the normal word.   It’s basically all accidentalish that it worked out this way.

Comment: @tchrist Hmm, very interestingish.

Comment: [“Oriented” vs. “orientated”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/oriented-vs-orientated), [regarding “Oriented” vs. “orientated”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162171/regarding-oriented-vs-orientated), [Is orientate a word? Does it matter where you are when using it?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/153411/is-orientate-a-word-does-it-matter-where-you-are-when-using-it) [Orienting or orientating?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32789/orienting-or-orientating)

Comment: @tchrist you mean workalised I hopelate?

Comment: I hear a lot of Americans say "disorientated" when I'm pretty sure they mean "disoriented." I believe this is a case of thinking that making a word more complicated than it needs to be somehow makes it correct.

Comment: @tchrist: "The normal word"?! Sigh.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I’m sorry that it bothers you to be outnumbered; I will therefore do what I can to help you out by keeping my own offspring to a bare minimum.

Comment: @tchrist: Excellent!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is British English.

If I'm disoriented them I'm unsure which way is up; I might feel sick and dizzy. Associations similar to vertigo. I could get disoriented flying an aircraft in thick fog or scuba diving in low visibility. Playing a computer game I could become disoriented, certainly, if the images are moving too fast for my brain to make sense of them properly.

If I'm disorientated then I'm simply lost. I'm feeling ok but I don't know where I am in relation to my surroundings. If I'm metaphorically disorientated then I'm confused, e.g. I might be disorientated by a new job.

If I'm disoriented then I am [spatially disorientated](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/558427/spatial-disorientation); I have lost spacial orientation.

> Spatial disorientation,  the inability of a person to determine his true body position, motion, and altitude relative to the earth or his surroundings. Both airplane pilots and underwater divers encounter the phenomenon.

http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/558427/spatial-disorientation

So *disorientated* has more of a topographical implication whereas *disoriented* is more sensory.

Comment: It seems odd to have different meanings for what's essentially the same word.

Comment: They're sometimes just used as synonyms.

Comment: For the entry at **disorient** (*v.tr*), the *Concise Oxford Dictionary* notes concisely '= disorientate. The COD lexicographers clearly see no difference in meaning.

The COD does not have entries for an adjective.

Comment: OK, they're *often* used as synonyms. ;)

Comment: I'd go for the *synonyms* option, AmE and BrE respectively. I don't know whether the Americans *orient* something, but the British would *orientate* it.

Answer (score -2):

If disoriented is a past participle, then one must assume that the infinitive, "to disorient" exists. Afaik it doesn't, so disorientated seems more probable.

Comment: No, that doesn’t follow.  The *-ed* suffix is used to make adjectives from nouns not just from verbs.  Consider *horn-rimmed glasses*: there is no such verb as *to horn-rim something*.

Comment: Compound adjectives are often formed from false participles like you "horn-rimmed", but the use of such false participles is usually limited to forming compound adjectives, which is, however, not the case in this example.

Comment: First, they are not “false participles”. They are merely adjectives formed from nouns instead from verbs. No participles are involved, real or false. Kindly read the OED’s entry for the **-ed²** *suffix*.  It gives examples like *horned, ringed, toothed, booted, wooded, moneyed, cultured, diseased, jaundiced, bigoted, crabbed, dogged* — amongst others.  Notice how not one of those is a compound (read: multiword) adjective, so that isn’t true either. It is, however, now impossible to tell those formed from nouns apart from those that had been formed from verb now lost to us.